# How can I include a header file that contains `>` in its name?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

This is quite a contrived problem, I admit, but here it is.

Suppose you have a file with the `>` character in its name. This is possible on most Unix systems *afaik*:

```
$ touch 'weird>name'
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user   0 28 Mag 11:05 weird>name
```

Now, suppose this file contains C/C++ code and you want to include it as an header:

```
#include <weird>name>

int main() {
  return weird_function();
}
```

Clang gives me the following error:

```
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'weird' file not found
#include <weird>name>
```

Of course, since the preprocessor parses the directive up to the first `>` and looks for the `weird` file. But, I wonder if some escaping mechanism exists to allow me to include the right file.

So, in C and/or C++, is there a way to include an header file which has the `>` character in its name?

**Edit:** Many suggested me why not to use `#include "weird>name"`. I admit that my mind slipped over the quotes syntax while writing the question, but it remains valid because the two syntaxes may ask the compiler to search in different paths (theoretically at least). So is there any escaping mechanism to let me include `weird>name` using the `#include <>` syntax?

Comment: Step 1: rename the file. Step 2: done.

Comment: How about adding the file as `#include "weird>name"`?

Comment: Yes, but that may search in different paths. I'll clarify.

Comment: In practice it might search in one additional path, which would only be a problem if you have files called `weird>name` in multiple places. If that's true, you need to sort your filenames out and stop doing dumb things :-P  The correct answer should be "who cares? just don't do that"

Comment: "but they have different search paths" - yes, '<>':  ["The intent of this syntax is to search for the files under control of the implementation."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)  thus you should never have to worry about this.  If you're including custom files with '<>' then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Using `#include "..."`, if the preprocessor can't find the header file in wherever it looks for, it will attempt `#include <...>` next with a possibly different search space.

Comment: @pmg Isn't that what Shravan40 and Jonathan Wakely and the OP said?

Comment: @Sneftel: it is the same; it is a little more noticeable on its own even if in a comment.

Comment: If you can't rename the file, then create a symbolic link to the file with better name.

Comment: Similar problem might exist if the filename contains characters that aren't in the source character set (which is implementation-defined). e.g. .h

Comment: @eerorika I don't see your point.... what has that got to do with intent?

Comment: The follow up is clearly now to include really"weird>name!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So, in C and/or C++, is there a way to include an header file which has the > character in its name?

Yes:

```
#include "weird>name"
```

> So is there any escaping mechanism to let me include `weird>name` using the `#include <>` syntax?

No. The characters between the `<` and `>` must be "any member of the source character set except new-line and `>`" ([[lex.header]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.header#nt:h-char)). <strike>Any escaped form of `>` would still be a way to represent the `>` character, which is not allowed.</strike> Edit: Implementations are allowed to support implementation-defined escape sequences there though (see [[lex.header] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.header#2) and its footnote).

The `#include " q-char-sequence "` form *does* allow the `>` character to appear, even though it might get reprocessed as `#include <...>` if searching as `"..."` fails ([[cpp.include] p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#3)).

The preprocessor also allows another form ([cpp.include] p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#4)), but its effect are implementation-defined, and the implementations I tried do not allow joining `weird` and `>` and `name` into a single preprocessor-token that can then be included

Comment: I admit that my mind slipped over the `"file"` syntax, but the question remains valid even if a little less fun, because `<>` and `""` may search in different paths

Comment: Next up: How can I include a header file that contains `"` in its name?

Comment: @gigabytes This is genuinely the only solution because of the way the language grammar is defined! http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#header-name

Comment: @gigabytes - generally `<>` means the preprocessor searches in system-defined locations (i.e. that are specific to the compiler), and `""` means it searches in user-defined locations (i.e. that you can specifiy).    No self-respecting compiler would come with a header file named like you describe, so you wouldn't use the `<>` form.

Comment: With compiler options you can set both paths.

Comment: But this is evidently not a self-respecting question, so you can suppose we are not using a self-respecting compiler :P

Comment: @gigabytes _"With compiler options you can set both paths."_ Yes, but not separately. Typically all paths searched for `<...>` are also searched for `"..."` if the first search fails. GCC's `-I-` option allows you to change that, but it's deprecated, and non-conforming, and broken, and not supported by other compilers.

Comment: Does it mean a file called `weird>name"` can never be included?

Comment: The rule is that *h-char-sequence* must not **contain** `>` (C 2018 6.4.7 1), not that the characters in it cannot **represent** `>`. If the C implementation defined some sequence of characters in an *h-char-sequence* that represented a `>` in a file system path, that would not violate the C standard. For example, `#include <weird%3ename>` would be allowed by the C standard, where `%3e` represented `>`.

Comment: I'm not sure the second part is right. Any attempt to escape `>` would not be actually a `>` character. That said, the preprocessor is not required to recognize any escape sequences in there.

Comment: Yes, I've changed that bit now.

Comment: @Kane, see the edit to the answer - it can never be included reliably, but some implementations might provide a way to do so.

Answer (score 8):

Ask the author of your compiler.

The C and C++ standards grant a lot of leeway to implementations over the interpretation of `#include` directives. There's no requirement that `#include <foo.h>` causes the inclusion of a file called "foo.h". For instance, a compiler can choose to ROT13 all the source file names if it likes. And for non-alphanumeric characters, the implementation can identify and remap certain character sequences. So if there were a platform where `>` regularly showed up in filenames, it's likely that a compiler for that platform would specify that, say, `\g` or something would be remapped to `>`. But the standard doesn't mandate a particular encoding.

Incidentally, the implementation could *also* just choose to allow `#include <weird>name>`. Since that is not well-formed under the language standards, an implementation is free to define a meaning for it as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try below syntax:

```
#include "weird>name"
```